# Just get the last value of a loop and stop function from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I have a color picker and on drag, it calls the function `hello(e,2)` continuously. I am passing 2nd variable 2 so that first `if statement` won't execute. Now, on continuous change, I don't want this.

```
list[2] =list[1];
list[1]=list[0];
list[0]=e;
```

This should be only executed the LAST time. So that the places just move once. I hope you understand my problem. This is my function.

```
function hello(e, a) {
    if (a == 1 && e != list[0] && e != list[1]) {
        list[2] = list[1];
        list[1] = list[0];
        list[0] = e;

        var strContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            strContent += "<div class=\"pick\" style=\"background-color:" + list[i] + "\" onclick=\"hello(this.style.backgroundColor,0);\"></div>";
        }
    }
    if (a == 2 && e != list[0] && e != list[1]) {
        list[0] = e;

        var strContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            strContent += "<div class=\"pick\" style=\"background-color:" + list[i] + "\" onclick=\"hello(this.style.backgroundColor,0);\"></div>";
        }
    }

    $('#colorpick').html(strContent);

    //clr = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    clr = e;
    var rgb = clr.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '').replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    myColor.r = parseInt(rgb[0]);
    myColor.g = parseInt(rgb[1]);
    myColor.b = parseInt(rgb[2]);
    curColor = myColor;

    document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-4').style.display = "none";

}
```

Comment: This is unreadable. Please indent your code properly.

Comment: _I hope you understand my problem._ I read it thrice but can't.

Comment: so you're saying that you don't want to pass "2" as the value of "a" the last time you call it? I think that's outside the control of the function you've shown us. The function itself doesn't know whether this is the first time you've called it or the millionth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to guess what you are trying to do there, mostly because I am sure it could have been done in a better manner.

```
function hello(e) {
   if(e === list[0] && e === list[1]){
      return false;
   }else{
      list.unshift(e);
   }

    var strContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        strContent += "<div class=\"pick\" style=\"background-color:" + list[i] + "\" onclick=\"hello(this.style.backgroundColor,0);\"></div>";
     }

     //followed by whatever code
}
```

It seems cleaner to me and should serve your purpose. Though not sure !!